# Is it possible to receive Supreme Kai from a Gold Awakening Capsule?

Tags: dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle

I am wondering if it is possible to receive a Supreme Kai (or Elder Kai) awakening medal from a golden awakening capsule?

The Item Effect *DOES* state: **"The ultimate, rarely obtainable awakening medal"** as opposed to another awakening medal from gold capsules; Kitibo, which states: **"Difficult to get."**

Any assistance or resources are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can receive Elder or Supreme Kai's from Golden Awakening Capsules.  I just received an Elder Kai from one.  This occurrence seems to be very rare, perhaps 1/20.

I hope this helps anyone else playing this great game!